# Automatically Testing of Web applications

Tags: java, php, security

I am currently working on an application for automatically testing of web applications, i.e. I try to inject malicious inputs (sqli or xss) into input fields of web applications. The problem is, that I am of course not allowed do test real world applications. 
My question is, do you know of "good" web applications, which are "meant" to be exploited (in a legal way)? I tested also the ones like DVWA, BodgeIt etc. but that's not what I am searching.

Comment: Good and meant to be exploit sounds exactly opposite to me

Comment: Yes. Of course i mean applications, that can be exploited legally without being a toy-example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [wargame](http://happyhacker.org/wargame/) is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Download a opensource web application, install it on your server/computer and then try to break it :) This is best solutions.

Plus if you find the bugs/security issues you can always send information to application maintainer with detailed description how to break application

Comment: both of you, thank you. for example, i downloaded the Central Authentication Service (http://www.jasig.org/cas) but that was just too easy to hack.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

"Selenium is a suite of tools specifically for automating web browsers."